# Extracting data from txt file and importing into a CSV

Tags: python, pandas, regex, dataframe, csv

I have data in a txt file in a format that looks like this.

```
ScanHeader # 1
position = 1, start_mass= 2.000000, end_mass = 535.010058
start_time = 0.034048, end_time = 0.000000, packet_type = 24
num_readings = 114, integ_intens = 14276257.301926, data packet pos = 1026
uScanCount = 0, PeakIntensity = 6799450.500000, PeakMass = 18.045876
Scan Segment = 0, Scan Event = 0
Precursor Mass 
Collision Energy 
Isolation width 
Polarity positive, Cenrtoid Data, Full Scan Type, MS Scan
SourceFragmentation Any, Type Ramp, Values = 0, Mass Ranges = 0
Turbo Scan Any, IonizationMode ElectronImpact, Corona Any
Detector Any, Value = 0.00, ScanTypeIndex = -1
DataPeaks

Packet # 0, intensity = 3691.226074, mass/position = 2.112536
saturated = 0, fragmented = 0, merged = 0

Packet # 1, intensity = 42881.203125, mass/position = 3.466080
saturated = 0, fragmented = 0, merged = 0

Packet # 2, intensity = 3006256.000000, mass/position = 4.184193
saturated = 0, fragmented = 0, merged = 0
```

Ideally, the output should be a csv file that looks like this:
[image]

I have tried using regex, as well as the read_csv option, but none seem to give me the desired output. The closest I've gotten is with regex, where I managed to extract all the data I needed but I had trouble putting it into the dataframe. The code looks like this:

```
from tabulate import tabulate
import re 

with open('2020-06-23-Didecylamine-deriv-0,1uL.txt') as newfile:
    data = re.findall(r'\d*last_scan = \d*\d.\d*', newfile.read())

with open('2020-06-23-Didecylamine-deriv-0,1uL.txt') as newfile:
    data1 = re.findall(r'\d* start_time = \d*\d.\d*', newfile.read())

with open('2020-06-23-Didecylamine-deriv-0,1uL.txt') as newfile:
    data2 = re.findall(r'\d* end_time = \d*\d.\d*', newfile.read())

with open('2020-06-23-Didecylamine-deriv-0,1uL.txt') as newfile:
    data3 = re.findall(r'\d*low_mass = \d*\d.\d*', newfile.read())

with open('2020-06-23-Didecylamine-deriv-0,1uL.txt') as newfile:
    data4 = re.findall(r'\d*high_mass = \d*\d.\d*', newfile.read())
    
with open('2020-06-23-Didecylamine-deriv-0,1uL.txt') as newfile:
    data5 = re.findall(r'\d*ScanHeader # \d', newfile.read())

with open('2020-06-23-Didecylamine-deriv-0,1uL.txt') as newfile:
    data6 = re.findall(r'\d*Packet # \d*', newfile.read())

with open('2020-06-23-Didecylamine-deriv-0,1uL.txt') as newfile:
    data7 = re.findall(r'\d* intensity = \d*\d.\d*', newfile.read())

with open('2020-06-23-Didecylamine-deriv-0,1uL.txt') as newfile:
    data8 = re.findall(r'\d* mass/position = \d*\d.\d*', newfile.read())

import pandas as pd

data = {'Scanheader': [data5],
        'Packet Number': [data6],
        'Intensity': [data7], 
        'Mass/Position': [data8]
        }

df = pd.DataFrame(data) 
df.to_csv('2020-06-23-Didecylamine-deriv-0,1uL.csv', index=False)
```

The output I am getting with this code looks like this:
[image]

I am aware that there are ways to make this code way less complicated, but I'm still a beginner and haven't found any ways to make it simpler that work. Any tips will be greatly appreciated :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should open your file only once.
You can first match the whole text for all ScanHeaders using `re` flags `re.MULTILINE + re.DOTALL`.
Iterate over these matches and extract Header # and time.
Finally iterate over the packets (found in the previous match) to extract the other columns:

```
data = []

scanHeader_pattern = re.compile(r'ScanHeader.*?(?=ScanHeader|\Z)', flags= re.MULTILINE + re.DOTALL)
packet_pattern = re.compile(r'Packet.*?(?=Packet|\Z)', flags= re.MULTILINE + re.DOTALL)

header_nb_pattern = re.compile(r'ScanHeader # (\d+)')
time_pattern = re.compile(r'start_time = (\d+\.\d+)', re.MULTILINE)

packet_nb_pattern = re.compile(r'Packet # (\d+)')
intensity_pattern = re.compile(r'intensity = (\d+\.\d+)')
mass_pos_pattern = re.compile(r'mass/position = (\d+\.\d+)')

for sh in re.findall(scanHeader_pattern, newfile.read()):
    h_nb = int(re.search(header_nb_pattern, sh).group(1))
    t = float(re.search(time_pattern, sh).group(1))
    
    for p in re.findall(packet_pattern, sh):
        p_nb = int(re.search(packet_nb_pattern, p).group(1))
        intensity = float(re.search(intensity_pattern, p).group(1))
        mass_pos = float(re.search(mass_pos_pattern, p).group(1))

        data.append(
            {'Scanheader': h_nb,
            'Packet Number': p_nb,
            'Time': t,
            'Intensity': intensity, 
            'Mass/Position': mass_pos
            }
        )

df = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

Comment: Thank you very much! I would upvote your response, but unfortunately I do not have enough reputation points. I tried the code and it works, except that the csv file only gives me the last header. Is there any way to fix that?

Comment: Check your indentation. Especially `data.append(...)`. Try printing data along the way.

Comment: Great, I found the error in my indentation. Thanks so much!